# Change VSCode Default Language for new files?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way in Visual Studio Code to change the default language that is used for new files?

By default if you open a new file, it's set for "Plain Text", I want this to be "HTML" instead.

I am often copy pasting HTML into VSC, editing a bit, then copying it back to a CMS I am using (the CMS editor is horrible). I don't want to save the code on my computer at all, just edit it a bit with HTML syntax highlighting, but I want that to be the default.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can now set the default language at either the user or workspace settings level using `files.defaultLanguage`:

```
"files.defaultLanguage": "html"
```

This can be done as a one off by changing the language mode:

1. <kbd>F1</kbd> to launch command palette
2. Type `lang`, <kbd>enter</kbd>
3. Type `html`, <kbd>enter</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, better than nothing I guess! :)

Comment: yeah this works but only for current open file. If i want to make all files affected ? any help ?

Comment: It's possible to set the default now, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 22):

Now you can do this change. Check out 
"files.defaultLanguage" in settings.

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted. This is the correct answer. `files.defaultLanguage` can be added to `settings.json`. Eg, `"files.defaultLanguage": "powershell"` (lowercase "p" required).

Comment: Note that it's case sensitive. I tried Powershell and it failed. When I did powershell as rootjul mentioned, it worked fine. Just thought I'd mention in case you speed read and miss that

Comment: @root Thanks for the lowercase 'p' comment, PowerShell wasn't working for me.

Comment: Would have been nice if the edited accepted answer had given a nod to this correct answer from almost a year earlier.

Answer (score 12):

With v1.42 you can either set

```
"files.defaultLanguage": "${activeEditorLanguage}"
```

and when you open a new untitled file with an html file as the last active file, the new file will automatically be assigned a languageMode of `HTML`.

Alternatively, pasting any html code into a new untitled file from a vscode editor will automatically be detected and the languageMode set to `HTML`.  Unless you have specifically set

```
"files.defaultLanguage": "plaintext"
```

then the languageMode will not be automatically detected as of v1.43.

---

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/68596936/836330 for a preview language detection feature in vscode 1.59.

Answer (score 5):

A slightly quicker way to accomplish what Daniel had answered:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd>, then <kbd>M</kbd>
2. Type `html`, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with VS Code. I wanted to default to Python when opening new files.
Solution: Click on File > Preferences > Settings. In the search area, Type: "files.defaultLanguage". Then fill in the language of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could create a scratch file with the `.html` extension? Open that when you need to do some copy/paste editing.