# How can I make VS Code auto detect the language by what I type and change the language mode to it?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

How can I make VS Code detect what language I type and automatically change mode to it?

For example, I use PHP scripts inside html code, but the extension of the file is .php
how can I make VS Code when I'm coding inside `<?php  ?>` area automatically detect that and change language mode to PHP, and when I'm coding outside `<?php  ?>` area automatically detect that and change language mode to html, and for example when I type a tag like `<style></style>` and begin to type inside it, automatically detect that and change language mode to CSS.

Answer (score 6):

Coming in vscode 1.59 is automatic language detection:

> #### Automatic language detection of Untitled files
>
> We're excited to announce the initial preview of automatic language
> detection of Untitled files which uses machine learning to detect
> which language you are coding in and automatically sets the language
> mode of the untitled file. This feature leverages the open source ML
> library, [Tensorflow.js](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/), and the ML
> model from [Guesslang](https://github.com/yoeo/guesslang) by GitHub
> user [@yoeo](https://github.com/yoeo).

The setting is `"workbench.editor.languageDetection": true,  (true = default)`

> > Note: If language detection isn't confident enough, then you will stay in your current language mode and no results will show in the
> > language picker until language detection has more confidence. The
> > setting also allows you to provide language overrides that can be used
> > to specify language modes you don't want to be automatically switched
> > off from. Given this example:

```json
 "[markdown]": {
   "workbench.editor.languageDetection": false 
}
```

Or `Workbench > Editor: Language Detection`

---

And in v1.65 more work and another setting on automatic language detection:

> ##### Improved automatic language detection
>
> When the new setting `workbench.editor.historyBasedLanguageDetection`
> is enabled, untitled editors will now use an improved automatic
> language detection algorithm that factors in your editor history and
> the contents of the current workspace to provide detection results
> with much less input text required

- from [v1.65 Release Notes](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_65.md#improved-automatic-language-detection)

Comment: From the wording it still sounds like it's a per file association so you can't have multiple different languages in a single file (like e.g. a .php file with HTML, PHP, CSS and JavaScript all in one)

Comment: I agree, syntax highlighing for different embedded files is a different issue.  You will have to test in with some embedded language code and see what it does.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that what you are requesting does not exist as per the documentation:

> In VS Code, we default the language support for a file based on its filename extension. However, at times you may wish to change language modes, to do this click on the language indicator - which is located on the right hand of the Status Bar. This will bring up the Select Language Mode drop-down where you can select another language for the current file.

Based on that, you can understand that VS Code's language detection is file extension based. However you can [associate languages with file extensions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_adding-a-file-extension-to-a-language). As per the documentation:

> For example, the setting below adds the .myphp file extension to the php language identifier:

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.myphp": "php"
}
```

Like that, you can associate your common languages to your common file extensions.

Answer (score 0):

VS Code can auto detect language extension by modifying the files.associations property.

Hit `control + P` and search for settings.json. Open that file and change the following line:

`"*.php": "properties"`  to `"*.php": "php"`

Answer (score 0):

#### From a Summary Lens

Quoting from the defaultSettings.json pseudo-file:

> ```json
> // Controls whether the language in a text editor is automatically detected
> // unless the language has been explicitly set by the language picker.
> // This can also be scoped by language so you can specify which languages
> // you do not want to be switched off of. This is useful for languages
> // like Markdown that often contain other languages that might trick
> // language detection into thinking it's the embedded language and not
> // Markdown.
> "workbench.editor.languageDetection": true,
>
> // When enabled, shows a Status bar Quick Fix when the editor language
> // doesn't match detected content language.
> "workbench.editor.languageDetectionHints": {
>   "untitledEditors": true,
>   "notebookEditors": true
> },
>
> // Enables use of editor history in language detection. This causes
> // automatic language detection to favor languages that have been recently
> // opened and allows for automatic language detection to operate with
> // smaller inputs.
> "workbench.editor.historyBasedLanguageDetection": true,
>
> // When enabled, a language detection model that takes into account editor
> // history will be given higher precedence.
> "workbench.editor.preferHistoryBasedLanguageDetection": false,
> ```

See also the `files.defaultLanguage` and `files.associations` settings.

#### From a Historical Lens

ML-based Language detection support was added to VS Code as a feature preview in [version 1.59](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_59#_automatic-language-detection-of-untitled-files), guarded under the setting "`workbench.editor.untitled.experimentalLanguageDetection`". The functionality is encapsulated in its own GitHub repo: [`Microsoft/vscode-languagedetection`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-languagedetection). The feature runs locally on the host machine, and uses [Tensorflow.js](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/) and the [Guesslang](https://github.com/yoeo/guesslang) model by GitHub user @yoeo.

The feature graduated from preview in [version 1.60](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_60#_automatic-language-detection), with the setting renamed to `workbench.editor.languageDetection`.

Heuristics for factoring in language modes you've used before / recently got added in [version 1.65](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_65#_improved-automatic-language-detection), togglable via the `workbench.editor.historyBasedLanguageDetection` setting.

[version 1.65](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_66#_improved-language-detection) change the default for the `workbench.editor.historyBasedLanguageDetection` setting to `true`, and added a new capability to give the history-based detection higher priority under the setting "`workbench.editor.preferHistoryBasedLanguageDetection`".

I'm not sure when the `workbench.editor.languageDetectionHints` setting got added.

Answer (score -1):

As of version 1.60 (August 2021) vscode includes automatic language detection.

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_60#_automatic-language-detection