# Create new untitled file and set language mode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have this macro

```
"macros": {
    "newScratchFile": [
        "workbench.action.files.newUntitledFile",
        "workbench.action.editor.changeLanguageMode"
    ]
},
```

Which used to work great with [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geddski.macros) but it appears Microsoft broke it as some point in time.

Now when I activate it, I do get a new untitled file, and the language mode popup opens for a split second but then disappears before I get a chance to type anything.

Is there a way to fix my macro so the language picker remains open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry to say it is probably the macro extension.  That extension has been "quiet" for awhile and the two PR's are pretty important (see the issues) and haven't been incorporated.  So the extension has been forked.  I was a big fan of the original macros extension but now I use [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) which works better.

I tried your commands in multi-command and it works flawlessly.

```
{
    "command": "multiCommand.newFileAndMode",
    // "interval": 250,
    "sequence": [

      "workbench.action.files.newUntitledFile",
      "workbench.action.editor.changeLanguageMode"
    ]
}
```

It also has support for an interval time between execution of the commands which occasionally comes in handy.  See, e.g., [vscode terminal: terminate process without prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46899480/vscode-terminal-terminate-process-without-prompt/52735332#52735332) my answer there to terminating a process and answering Y and enter in one keychord from a texteditor or terminal which wouldn't work without the delay - for the process to terminate.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/68596936/836330 for automatic language detection once you add some code.

Comment: [Issue 152920](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/152920) could be of interest, for VSCode 1.70 (July 2022), released to VSCode insiders