# Alternative way of creating new file in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When creating new file in VS Code, it just opens a blank empty file right away.

Is there a way to create a specific type of new file, like in Notepad++ you can choose the language for the file. In VS Code you get to choose the file extension only when saving the file for the first time.

It'd be a bit faster to create a new, for example, JavaScript file instead of creating empty file and saving it as .js file and then writing to it.

So far I've created files with basic Notepad (with the "show file extensions" option enabled from File Explorer) and when naming the new file, writing the extension at the end instead of .txt

Comment: Try the following (assuming you are in Windows with default keybindings), Ctrl + n (make a new file). Press Ctrl +k, release and press m, you can now type javascript to change to detect the file as a js file

Comment: @Countingstuff yeah, I am on Windows machine. Those shortcuts worked. Thanks!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54319412/create-new-untitled-file-and-set-language-mode/54320432#54320432 for a way to automate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyboard shortcuts [mentioned by @CountingStuff in this comment worked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55435805/alternative-way-of-creating-new-file-in-vs-code#comment97589031_55435805).

Here are the step-by-step instructions:

1. Create a new file:

   > <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>
2. Change the syntax language:

   > <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>M</kbd>

   In the drop down that appears, auto-complete or manually choose a language option.

   [image: VS Code: Select Language Mode input]

The vscode documentation for this can be found here:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_language-id

Answer (score 0):

You could just open the integrated terminal ``` CTRL+`` ``` and `touch` your file.

Answer (score 0):

I've remapped my keyboard shortcuts so that CTRL+N triggers the "File > New File" menu item. Now, when I press CTRL+N it adds a new entry in the file explorer and I can add a new file from there. I can also utilise VSCode's file explorer creation mechanism to create files in subfolders by pre-fixing the file with the directory structure, so typing `src\index.js` will create a new file named index.js in the src directory.

Reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2QBYlfSQA6s