# Turned off the programming language selection in VSCode, how to turn it on again?

Tags: visual-studio-code

As in the title, I accidentally turned off the possibility to detect the programming language in VS Code, which is a nice feature.
I am looking for weeks now and I found nothing anywhere to solve this.
Does somebody know where I can turn it back on again?
Thank you!

Comment: you can do it with `Shift+Ctrl+P` and type `language`, or right click on the status bar

Comment: Are you looking for the automatic language detection feature?  You can re-enable if you disabled it, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/68596936/836330.