# Can I configure specific VSCode extensions to only be enabled based on the current language?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to know if it is possible to create different instances of programming in VSCode?

( -- In case it wasn't clear -- )

Idea: I want to program in a certain language and I want my extensions active only for that language.

I read a little about VSCode Workspaces, but I didn't understand.

Comment: disable all your language extensions globally, enable them per Workspace if needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to organize your extensions in VSCode. VSCode gets a bit clunky after installation of many extensions (made even worse in a corporate laptop that has many security scanning tools enabled in the background).

I used to use workspaces to configure my extensions but I find it troublesome having to reinstall extensions for every new project.

**Since [2023 July's release of VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_81), there is a new feature called [VSCode Profiles](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/profiles).**

In each "Profile", you can configure language/framework specific settings.

Profiles can be accessed from the "File" Menu.

[image: File Menu]

For example, I have these profiles:

- Default - *Intellicode*, *Material Icon Theme*, *GitLens*, *WSL* (This profile acts as a "base" profile of what my other profiles should have).
- Solidity - *Solidity* extension on top of extensions in Default profile
- Python - *Python, Pylance, Microsoft Black Formatter* on top of extensions in Default profile

**Profiles are specific to the opened VSCode instance. So it is possible to open 2 VSCode instances (Ctrl+shift+n) each with a specific profile. E.g. python backend in VSCode window 1, React frontend profile in VSCode window 2.**

I first set up Default profile to contain the extensions I want for all my other profiles. When installing an extension you want to apply for all other profiles, ensure you select ["Apply extension to all profiles" by right-clicking the extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_81#_apply-an-extension-to-all-profiles).

[image: Apply extension to all profiles]

Then, to create a language/framework-specific VSCode profile, I create it like this.

1. File > Preferences > Profiles > Create Profile...
2. Ensure "Extensions" is checked under the "Choose what to configure in your profile" (this will ensure any new extensions you install will only remain in this profile).

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what I was imagining VSCode had, having too many extensions could cause conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

VS Code extension enablement has two "layers": The "global layer", and the "workspace layer". You can control enablement globally, and then override the global value on a per-workspace basis. As far as I know at the time of this writing, there is no way to enable/disable an extension only for a particular file, or for files of a particular language, or for a particular root in a multi-root workspace.

What I'd suggest is to only leave globally enabled the extensions that you're pretty sure you'll want enabled for all workspaces, and then enable the rest on a per-workspace-basis.

You could/should also check if the extension of interest contributes a setting to allow you to filter / exclude certain files by language association / mode, or by path glob patterns.

Note that VS Code already has basic language-mode detection capabilities (see [this post of mine for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77333757/11107541)), and also that VS Code extensions can register [events upon which they activate](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/activation-events) (I.e., they are not activated by the VS Code extension machinery until one of those events happen).

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to vscode settings.
2. Click [image] at the right top to enter text mode.
3. Then you can config different settings for different languages according to this example:

[image]