# How to put a marker in files for VSCode to use the language specified regardless of the file extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

For example, let's say you have a file called `bla.yaml.tmpl` and as the name ends with `.tmpl`, VSCode will not switch to YAML mode unless you manually do it or add it to some config.

I'm looking for the way to add a 'marker' in the file itself (as a special comment, like in emacs for instance), so the language mode is automated regardless of the file extension and without requiring any manual setting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to associate a file extension with a certain language in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973619/how-to-associate-a-file-extension-with-a-certain-language-in-vs-code)

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/77333757/11107541

Answer (score 0):

This nifty extension does exactly that:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chrislajoie.vscode-modelines