# VS Code autodetects CSS instead of HTML now - how do I fix it?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, detection

Not a coder/developer per se. My experience is limited to HTML dev for email specifically. Most of the time, I copy the code from our platform and paste it into a new file, make my edits, copy and paste back into our platform. I rarely save files outside of our platform. VS Code always autodetected the HTML, and my Live Preview worked perfectly. After the latest VS Code update two days ago, it no longer identifies our code as HTML but rather as CSS, or worse, as Plain Text. I can click the language in the status bar and select HTML but what a pain!

All of our code starts with a doctype declaration  and with  to accommodate Outlook/Live. I don't know how that is completely ignored.

I would appreciate any assistance that can help fix this!

- I have HTML CSS Support (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ecmel.vscode-html-css) installed. After discovering the issue I noticed it had an update, so installed the update hoping that would solve. Did not.
- I changed my settings so that the default new file type is HTML. Pasting my code in seemed to override that, and I had to manually set the language back to HTML.
- I've wasted 2 hours looking into possible solutions, trying to find some post somewhere about someone with a similar issue. Nada.

Most online info about VS Code is written with the assumption that users have a certain base level of knowledge of coding and the tools used and I am so far below that level. If anyone could help me out, and explain it to me like I'm a child, I would appreciate it!

Comment: My _guess_ is that the language auto-detect feature is just not coming to the right conclusion, and there is no setting specifically to change how it works. As a workaround, you could try to straight up disable that option in your settings so it sticks with your default language. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50692174/how-can-i-make-vs-code-auto-detect-the-language-by-what-i-type-and-change-the-la/68596936#68596936

Comment: Thank you, I'll give that a try. I did see this post yesterday in my hunt but I was still hoping to find a fix for the faulty detection, which would be my ideal solution. I also work in json, though less frequently, so the auto detection was very useful. But if turning off the detection gives me HTML automatically, I'll take it and just select json when I need to.