# VS Code Change Language Using Keybinding

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, key-bindings

Is there a keybinding `command` string to change the language mode to a specific language?

I'd like to have a hotkey to change the language mode to JavaScript. For example, <kbd>Ctrl + L</kbd><kbd>Ctrl + J</kbd>:

```json
{
  "key": "ctrl+l ctrl+j",
  "command": ???,
  "args": ???
}
```

This GitHub issue ["Expose 'change language' as command"](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/1800) makes me think that it has been implemented.

I often find myself researching VS Code keybindings and settings commands like this, and I haven't found reliable documentation for them. **Please include your source when answering** to help me out.

Update: I found this extension, [`vscode-change-language-mode`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=usernamehw.change-language-mode). I'll try it out, but I'd still like to know if there's native support for it.

---

Related things that aren't answers to my question:

- [Change Language Mode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/tips-and-tricks#_change-language-mode) shortcut <kbd>Ctrl + K</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> command: `"workbench.action.editor.changeLanguageMode"`.
- [Default Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35904221/change-vscode-default-language-for-new-files) setting: `"files.defaultLanguage"`.
- [File Associations](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers)

Comment: AFAIK, there's no support for `args` in `workbench.action.editor.changeLanguageMode`. A bunch of issues that literally asked for the ability to invoke it with specified language were closed as a duplicate of that one (#1800). An API for extensions was introduced, but no native support. You should probably create a new issue.

Comment: I'll let this question sit for a day or two, and then open an issue if we don't find anything else out. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Forgot the source: Source: **Trust me**.