# How to set the default language for files without an extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am NOT asking about [the default type for *new* files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35904221/241142), but rather files I open that have no extension.  I want `some_file` to be treated as a shell script, and never as plain text.  How can I do this?

Comment: Consider adding an extension to the file for development purposes, but *deploying* the script without an extension. Put another way, "build" `tmp.sh` using `cp tmp.sh tmp`.

Comment: @chepner: that sounds like more pain than manually setting the file type every time I open the file.  Also, these are not deployed: they are sourced locally.  In some cases adding a `.sh` would break everything.  I haven't tested but I'm pretty sure my Z shell rc file can't be named `.zshrc.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

This has been a problem for a while it seems:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/1800

But you could try adding an empty string `""` representing no file extension, to your file associations or language identifiers:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers

Answer (score 0):

Since

> "I want some_file to be treated as a shell script, and never as plain
>   text"

try

```
"files.associations": {
  "plaintext": "shellscript"
},
```

will be sufficient.  The language mode will still appear as "Plain Text" but syntax highlighting, etc. should act as "Shell Script".