# Visual Studio Code Python File Type

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Is there a VS Code configuration to make a project's new file default create python files without defaulting VS Code as a whole?

When I create a new file, give it a name, and append .py VS Code will recognize it as a python file. If I just create a file and name it, it will default to a .txt extension.

Here is what I have done so far:

- Install the latest version of Python https://www.python.org/downloads/
- Install the VS Code Python extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python
- Restart PC
- Open a blank git repo only containing a readme.md
- Select the python 3.9.5 interpreter

Here is what I see when I try to add blank file named *new*.

[image]

Comment: Why would you want files without extensions be python files? What's wrong with typing out `.py`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35904221/change-vscode-default-language-for-new-files

Comment: I don't know any editor that does something similar, next request is that files created in `/style/` should be `.css` files unless I want it to be a `.sass` file

Comment: @nobleknight I didn't think about setting it at the workspace level. That in combination with creating a file using `ctrl` + `n` as shown in [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/g8kogu/beginner_question_how_do_i_set_my_default_new/foo2ctu?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) does the trick. Please add an answer with these links and I will mark it correct.

Comment: Slight nitpick: The default extension (in your gif) is _no extension (not .txt)!_ Remember that the file extension doesn't matter -- regardless of the extension, you can open a file as text and the python interpreter can interpret any text file as long as it contains valid python code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done at the project level but can be done in the workspace.

Open the settings for the workspace (Manage (cog wheel in the bottom right) > Settings > type "language" into the search bar > save).
When in the workspace press `ctrl` + `n` to create a new page. By default this should now create a python page!

Big thanks to @[nobleknight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14429185/nobleknight) for pointing out the workspace settings.

Related links:

- [Change VSCode Default Language for new files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35904221/change-vscode-default-language-for-new-files)
- [Change default save type](https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/g7y988/is_it_possible_to_change_the_default_save_as_type/).