VS Code keybinding to open new-untitled file with specific language mode?
Is there any way to create a keybinding or something like that so every time I open a new untitled filed with "ctrl + n", it creates a new file with the extension of the file i was working on? for example if i am working with an file.py, it should create a new-untitled.py file.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60292872/836330 - I think that answers your question.

@Mark that was my first thought too, but I don't think it's the same. this question has room for making multiple such bindings each wanting a different language mode.

In keybindings.json:
{
    "key": "", // TODO
    "command": "workbench.action.files.newUntitledFile",
    "args": {
        "languageId": "plaintext", // TODO
    },
},

Run "Change Language Mode" in the command palette to see a list of language IDs.
Note that there is also a setting to set the default language mode for new untitled files: files.defaultLanguage.
If you instead want to be prompted automatically to select a language mode, see Create new untitled file and open language mode quick pick. Or, to change the default language mode for all new untitled files, see Change VSCode Default Language for new files?.
